# Как с помощью XSLT создать наипростейший шаблон

Tags: xslt

есть xml(30K строк) которую на 1 - ом этапе обработке нужно превратить в шаблон.

```
<Test>
    <data_type>numeric</data_type>
    <value>83.79</value>
</Test>
<OBJECTIVE>
      <data_type>string</data_type>
      <value>string</value>
</OBJECTIVE>
<EDITIONDATE>
          <data_type>string</data_type>
          <value>string</value>
          <date_format>yyyyDDD</date_format>
</EDITIONDATE>
```

Если опереться на value и в зависимости от него value=83.79 - 1 логика value=string проверить нет ли на одном уровне date_format если есть значит дата.Я состряпал

```
<xsl:template match="//value">
        <xsl:variable name="val" select="string(value)"/>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$val = string">
                <xsl:text>string</xsl:text>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$val=83.79">
                <xsl:text>numeric</xsl:text>
            </xsl:when>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
```

Отрабатывает только 2 - ое т.к он всегда думает, что там 83.79 искал приведение типов не нашел. Как должен выглядить шаблон решающий мою задачу?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это выражение:

```
select="string(value)"
```

присваивает переменной пустую строку, т. к. в текущем контексте нет узла `value` (вы его уже нашли в выражении `match`).
Очевидно, должно быть:

```
select="string(.)"
```

---

Далее, в выражении

```
test="$val = string"
```

происходит сравнение с *узлом* по имени `string`. Естественно, такого узла нет.
Должно быть:

```
test="$val = 'string'"
```

Значение литерала берите в кавычки.
Число, по идее, тоже нужно окавычить, хотя парсер и без кавычек понимает, что это не имя узла.